False Negative vs False Positive for Multiclass classification
Suppose I have three classes 1,2,3.
And there's evaluation like below, where second element is false prediction where model predict class 3 while ground truth is 2.
y_true = [1,2,3]
y_pred = [1,3,3]

I'm making visualization tool, where

red if prediction by model is class 1 and ground truth is not class 1
green if prediction by model is class 2 and ground truth is not class 2
blue if prediction by model is class 3 and ground truth is not class 3
no color for true prediction

What false type is the second element? False positive or false negative?
From my case above, second element would blue colored.

This is confusing because calling a classification positive or negative is only really meaningful when there are only two options (positive/negative). If there are more options, there are multiple types of classification errors. You could squeeze this into a binary framework, but it seems more reasonable to me to just colour by whether the classification is correct or wrong. Though of course, this will depend on the nature of the problem you are developing the visualisation for. I would also add that it's valuable for you to present the full confusion matrix, whatever the colour scheme chosen.

To answer your specific question, the first 3 cases are incorrect prediction, and hence should all be colored red, and the 4th one should be colored green (correct prediction). Strictly speaking, past a 2x2 confusion matrix, there really is no longer a false positive/negative concept (because there are more than 2 choices -positive, negative-), but there still can be a "correct prediction/incorrect prediction" choice. For a 3x3 confusion matrix (your case), the diagonal are the "correct" predictions, and all the other cells are "incorrect". A common technique is to use the same color for all cells, but change the shade according to the proportion in that cell (darker for larger proportion, lighter for smaller ones). You may want to take a look here, for a nice discussion, and some examples.

Shading? It's already visualized for ground truth for my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78745091/how-to-make-colorful-line-legend?noredirect=1#comment138835771_78745091

The concept of the false negative and false positive are useful because they allow us to distinguish among different kinds of classification errors, and treat them differently. Sometimes we only worry about whether we got something right or not (as in a true/false exam), but in some fields we are more worried about false negatives (like in medical diagnosis, missing a real case of serious disease can be fatal), while in others we are more worried about false positives (like in a clinical trial for a new drug, we don't want to falsely approve useless drugs).
In a three-class problem you actually have six different types of classification errors, in which you wrongly call each of the three classes as one of the two incorrect classes. There is no longer a concept of a false negative or false positive with three classes. How you want to treat these six distinct errors is up to you and the domain knowledge - maybe certain types of errors are more costly than others and should be highlighted, while others are not as serious. If all your types of errors are equivalent, you could highlight them all as the same color, since any misclassification is equivalent to any other. But this is all highly dependent on the actual meaning of the misclassifications.
